# Use data from ajax call without using async: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm pretty new to JS/ajax and was a bit confused on ajax data/success returns.

I have the following ajax code. I want it to run the code in `succes:` after the ajax call has received the json from the imgur api.

It is only working for me with `async: false`. I thought the bit in `success:` would only run after the data has been retrieved, but for some reason data is null if aysnc is true.

I've read a lot of SO answers/jQuery documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to not hang the browser with `async: false`

This code might be running 100+ times on a page (i.e. reddit.com/r/pics with 100 links loaded on one page), so `async: false` is not only bad practice but also renders the page unusable for 5 to 6 seconds, which is unacceptable.

I've tried making ajax a `var` then calling that var `.success(function(data) ...);` but it still does not work. I've also tried replacing success with complete.

It all only ever works with `async: false`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/" + hash,
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers:{
                        'Authorization':'Client-ID c606aeeec9ca098'
                    },
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.data.is_album == true) {
                            if(data.data.images_count == 1){
                                el[j].href = el[j].href.replace(/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?imgur.com\/gallery\/.*/, data.data.images[0].link);
                            }else{
                                el[j].href = el[j].href.replace(/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?imgur.com\/gallery\//, "https://imgur.com/a/");
                            }
                        } 
                        else{
                            el[j].href = el[j].href.replace(/(.*)?(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?imgur.com\/.*/, data.data.link);
                        }                 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You can use promise.

Comment: Can you add an example of values for the `hash` variable to be able to test ?

Comment: Otherwise, a Common way to debug this type of thing is to just `console.log(data)` in the `success` and the `fail` function to view what happened. In this code, you haven't put the `fail` field so you will not see anything if the request fail.

Comment: _"This code might be running 100+ times on a page"_ With async, you may be hitting some sort of throttling.

Comment: Sure! An example hash is `qXEdY`. I also logged it and it seems like my data being returned is always successful (status: 200 in data), but the console does not modify the `href` link like it does when `async: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the jQuery Deferred object (Promises interface) to be helpful. It allows you to do stuff like:

```
var promise = $.ajax("/myServerScript1");

function getStuff() {
    return $.ajax("/myServerScript2");
}

promise.then(getStuff).then(function(myServerScript2Data){
  // Do something with myServerScript2Data
});
```

Resource (this is well written and a necessary read for anyone using AJAX):

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html

Comment: this does not seem to answer the specific question nor it points out what's wrong with the op code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what doesn't work on your code but I can tell you what is not recommended.

1. Always have a failure handler : You have to put a function in the `fail` field of your request object. If you don't, you will not be able to see any errors.
2. Keep the test simple : You should begin by only displaying the value of the request result instead making some calculation with it. This way you can debug ONLY the request call and you are sure that the problem doesn't came from the calculation code
3. Use Promises API : As previously pointed by the @gibberish, the modern way to do what you want is to use Promises. You can use jQuery's promises or any other like ES6 Promises (that one requires a compilation time for most of browsers)

Comment: Thanks! I implemented an error field but it's never being called, even with `async: true`. I also did console.log(data) within success and it returns valid data! The json is exactly what I get when `aysnc: false`. However, it seems like the href replace isn't doing it's job, and I'm not sure why. And I'm looking into promises now, thanks for the suggestion!